# css in <style> block not applied on build

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit

I have a new Svelte app using Sveltekit, skeleton project. I create a component with a single div and attempt to set a background image. I am using [adapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static) to generate a static site on build. If inline the css on the div, it works fine. If I create a class in the `<style>` block of the component then the styles do not load.

1. The component:

```html
<div class="foo-test" 
     style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image: url('circle.png');">
</div>
```

2. `npm run build`. files created:

[image]

3. it works:

[image]

4. change the component to use css in `<style>` block:

```html
<div class="foo-test"></div>
<style>
.foo-test {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-image: url("circle.png");
}
</style>
```

5. build again. files created. No css applied:

[image]

My `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        prerender: {
            default: true
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Am I missing a step to the process? New to Svelte. TIA

Edits:

app.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%svelte.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        %svelte.head%
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>%svelte.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit2: I should note, it works correctly then running in dev `npm run dev` and launch browser to `http://localhost:3000/`. only the index.html file generated from the adapter-static is not working properly when I open the file in the browser `file:///C:/Repos/foo/foo/build/index.html`

Comment: Don't use screenshots of code; copy+paste the code into the post directly so it is more readable and searchable.

Comment: updated to replace screenshots with code blocks

Comment: What do you have in `app.html`? Perhaps `%svelte.head%` (which is where the stylesheet reference is injected) isn't in the right place?

Comment: just the out-of-the-box app.html. See edit

Comment: Does the image file get copied into the build directory in the second (i.e. CSS) build? Perhaps it is being copied automatically because it is inline in the first build, but you might have to copy it manually (or through explicit action) in the second build because it's not part of the actual code, but only the CSS definition? Just a guess... You could try an `import 'circle.png'` (with the proper relative path, obviously) to see if that changes anything.

Comment: yes. the image is copied every time. Even if i remove the image from the picture, the css isn't getting applied from the `<style>` block at all

Comment: are the css files generated ? maybe you have a version with a bug, consider updating sveltekit as well (currently there is a release almost every day)

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice none of the other styles were applied either, my bad.

Comment: @stephane-vanraes there is a single css file in `build/_app/assets/pages/index.svelte-{hash}.css`. The contents are what I expect based on the css in my component

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are deploying to Github Pages and you have not included a `.nojekyll` file. I saw this behaviour and resolved it by adding `.nojekyll` in the `/static` directory.

It appears that Jekyll does not recognise the directories with a leading underscore.

If using `gh-pages` to deploy, you also need to use the `--dotfiles` options to ensure that the file is pushed.

Note: I still don't see that loading the built files directly works locally, but I am not sure that that would be expected behaviour.